# Searchkick with Rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, rolify, searchkick

I have a Rails 4 app and I am trying to search my Task model using the [Searchkick](http://github.com/ankane/searchkick) gem. But, I only want the search results to include Tasks that the current user has a certain [Rolify](http://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) role for. Basically, the user can't search for other user's Tasks.

The Rolify gem has a method for getting the Tasks that the current user has a certain role for.

```
Task.with_role(:viewer, current_user) #=> Tasks where the current user has a viewer role.
```

I cannot figure out how to filter the Searchkick results to only search the Tasks returned in the code above. I want to do something like this,

```
Task.with_role(:viewer, current_user).search("foo") #=> Returns all Tasks that match foo
```

But, it includes all Tasks that match *foo* instead of just the current user's Tasks that match *foo*. I know that there is a UsersRoles table that Rolify uses to relate the users and roles, but I don't know how to relate that to the Task model's roles.

Is it possible to search the Task model's roles for a certain role that belongs to the current user all in a Searchkick query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Searchkick/elaticsearch-rails's `records` feature to do this.

```
Task.search("foo").records.with_role(:viewer, current_user)
```

`records` converts the results into essentially a `where(id: [ids, matching, the, elasticsearch, query])` scope that you can add other queries onto.

Comment: FYI, `records` loses Elasticsearch's [scoring](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/480#issuecomment-127899183)